# mDNS advertising in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mdns, avahi

I would like to make dart program that run on Linux and windows.
My app will talk to the program using mDNS to find the program computer IP and send requests.

In my search I found only mDNS lookup/discovery packages.

Is it possible to advertise/broadcast mDNS name that is different from the computer host name.

If so how can I set mDNS broadcast name of my choosing using dart.

In the example of [multicast_dns](https://pub.dev/packages/multicast_dns/example) flutter official package for mDNS I didn't saw any example for that only lookup.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'd like to implement something similar.

Comment: Not that I remember. Something else that might help you is searching mDNS devices, which I have added into network_tools package.

Comment: Please upvote this issue for flutter team to add support for broadcasting mDNS https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88243